# Change the detail page data on swipe in Windows Phone 8

Tags: windows-phone-8

Testing Windows Phone 8 Apps using MVVM framework.

ListPage.xaml:

```
<phone:PanoramaItem x:Name="mpnP"  Width="475">
    <Grid Style="{StaticResource GridPanoPage}" >
         <ListBox x:Name="pkList" Style="{StaticResource ListBoxHeadlines}" >
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate >
                    <ListBoxItem Style="{StaticResource ListBoxItemHub}">
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                            <Image x:Name="pkImage" Source="{Binding ImagePath}" />
                            <StackPanel>
                                <TextBlock x:Name="pkHead" Text="{Binding Head}"/>
                             </StackPanel>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </ListBoxItem>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>
     </Grid>
</phone:PanoramaItem>
```

On List Box selection changed , navigate to detail page on the basis of ID-

```
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Session.ID))
NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/Views/Detail.xaml", UriKind.Relative));
```

Now I want to navigate  to next ID on Swipe screen. means -
if ID -- 3 is currently on screen and if user Swipe the screen then next ID detail will display on screen.
This process done till list box last id.

Answer (score 0):

On the details page, can with the help of a FlipView navigate between several items. And every time the event SelectionChange occurs change the Id in ViewModel.

```
<toolkit:FlipView x:Name="FlipViewImages" ItemsSource="{Binding Images}" >
            <toolkit:FlipView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <utils:ImageZoomControl Url="{Binding}"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </toolkit:FlipView.ItemTemplate>
            <toolkit:FlipView.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <VirtualizingStackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"/>
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </toolkit:FlipView.ItemsPanel>
        </toolkit:FlipView>
```

The FlipView is not a native control, you have to import through the nuget Manager, Windows Phone ToolKit.
If your Item Source is a list of objects do not need to do anything else.